# Liferay group private pages first load time is slow

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

Problem: I have a multi-group Liferay application, there are two servers one for production and one for UAT on UAT everything is running smoothly but on production, every private page of a group is taking a lot of time for the first load.

The problem occurred when a group creation failed, I have replicated the production environment on UAT and remove the corrupted group but the result is the same, as per my understanding the issue lies with the permission of the private page if the page is moved to the public page it loads quickly.

Comment: There are many things to understand better, decompose the problem in small problems

Comment: as I did mention that the issue is only with private pages